# Internal Server Error on new next app project

Tags: next.js, npx

I've created next project with a command "npx create-next-app@latest"
All options are set as a default and the project is created and let the server start successfully
The problem is that I browse the localhost:3000, the error came out.
I could see the error on the browser 'Internal server error'
[image]

the console prints out the error as follows.
[image]

In other computer, it works fine but not sure why it is not working on my side.